# iOS 8.3 HouseArrest with iTunesMoibleDevice.dll not working

Tags: itunes, mobile-devices

It seems that starting with iOS 8.3, the "iTunesMobileDevice" hack to "HouseArrest" an application folder for reading/writing is broken.

I noticed that some commercial companies mention 8.3 support in there releases notes, but nobody is willing to share what has to be done to fix it.

https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/release-notes

> iOS 8.3 compatibility - allows read/write access to Documents folder
>   in apps that have iTunes file sharing enabled

[Here](https://github.com/ImagineLearning-Public/MobileDevice/blob/master/MobileDevice/iPhone.cs#L87) is the code that doesn't work with 8.3.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

**EDIT**: After digging further, the error is "InstallationLookupFailed". After reading [this](https://bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess/issue/8/os-x-10103), apparently, there is no fix. :(